# How to delete old MediaWiki revisions when deleteOldRevisions run out of memory

Tags: sql, mediawiki

is there a possibilty to delete revisions , when the maintenance skript deleteOldRevisions runs out of memory (tried to allocate more than 2 GB under 32bit). I not even get the list of the ids to delete it step by step.

Maybe directly using SQL?

I tried/read already https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Reduce_size_of_the_database
and also [Use SQL to delete old MediaWiki revisions without shell access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870048/use-sql-to-delete-old-mediawiki-revisions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mmm, yeah... after taking a peek at [that script](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-core/blob/master/maintenance/deleteOldRevisions.php), I'm not surprised it fails.  It really should be fixed to iterate over the pages instead of just building a huge list in memory.  I suppose the only reason it hasn't been is that, for wikis like Wikipedia, deleting revisions isn't really something one normally ever does.

Anyway, besides fixing the script, I see a bunch of possible workarounds:

- The deleteOldRevisions.php script can take a list of page IDs.  You could just try running for each page on your wiki, one at a time.  You could even write a simple shell script to run it in a loop, starting at page ID 1 and counting up to whatever the current maximum page ID on your wiki is.
- Alternatively, you could [make a dump of your wiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aDumpBackup.php) containing only the lastest revision of each page, then delete all pages on your wiki (i.e. everything in the `page`, `revision` and `text` tables) and import them back from the dump.
- In principle, if you [know what you're doing](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aDatabase_layout), you *can* also delete old revisions directly using SQL.

  The first things you *always* want to do before messing with the database are to set your wiki to [read-only mode](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgReadOnly) and make a [full backup](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aBacking_up_a_wiki).  If you haven't done this before, it's also a good idea to practice *restoring* the backup onto a local test wiki before doing anything irrevocable to your real wiki.

  Then, to delete all but the latest revision of each page, run the following SQL command:

  ```
  DELETE FROM revision WHERE NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT * FROM page WHERE page_id = rev_page AND page_latest = rev_id )
  ```

  Note that the command above will only delete the old revision *metadata*, not the actual text of those revisions.  The easiest way to get rid of the old text records is to run the [purgeOldText.php](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aPurgeOldText.php) maintenance script, although you *should* be able to do it using SQL too, something like:

  ```
  DELETE FROM text WHERE NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT * FROM revision WHERE rev_text_id = old_id )
  ```

  Finally, if everything went well, I recommend running the [rebuildall.php](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aRebuildall.php) maintenance script to fix things like recent changes that will otherwise point to deleted revisions.  Then make sure that everything looks as it should and turn read-only mode off again.
- Finally, if you're doing this to try and save space, consider [compressing your old revisions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aCompressOld.php) instead of just outright deleting them.  This will save a significant amount of space while still keeping all the revisions available on your wiki.