# Delete old revisions in Mediawiki

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

I have tried the [deleteOldRevisions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3ADeleteOldRevisions.php) script, but it kept running for hours without completing the job. I have read relevant questions like this one: [How to delete old MediaWiki revisions when deleteOldRevisions run out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550735/how-to-delete-old-mediawiki-revisions-when-deleteoldrevisions-run-out-of-memory) but the suggested MySQL queries do not seem to work on MW 1.31 or 1.32. For example:

```
DELETE FROM revision WHERE NOT EXISTS
( SELECT * FROM page WHERE page_id = rev_page AND page_latest = rev_id )
```

outputs:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1.
```